# How to format output when using Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting

1. As in the title, I want to output the image of a 3D body with its volume and surface area shown nicely beside it. (Maybe in a table?) But how can I do it?
2. Is it possible to calculate the surface area for each specific facets?

For example, consider the simple case:

```
Manipulate[
  {RegionPlot3D[x + y + z < A, {x, 0, 1 - A}, {y, 0, 1 - A}, {z, 0, 1 - A}, 
     PlotRange -> {0, .5}],
   NIntegrate[Boole[x + y + z < A], {x, 0, 1 - A}, {y, 0, 1 - A}, {z, 0, 1 - A}]}, 
  {A, 0, .99}]
```

What I can get so far is showing both the plot and data but not formatting it well.

[image: Current progress]

Comment: Formatting: `PlotLabel`, `Row`, `Column`, `Grid`, `Labeled`,....  Question 1 is a little vague, but `Row` might be what you're after.  I think you'll have to play around to see.  The second question might be better asked as a separate question.

Comment: For formatting output in a Manipulate, study the four functions `Style`, `Row`, `Column`, and `Grid`. In this case I would most likely use `Grid`.

Comment: Thanks a lot fellows! It works out great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
   Manipulate[
     Grid[{{

        RegionPlot3D[
         x + y + z < A, {x, 0, 1 - A}, {y, 0, 1 - A}, {z, 0, 1 - A}, 
         PlotRange -> {0, .5}],

        PaddedForm[Round[NIntegrate[
           Boole[x + y + z < A], {x, 0, 1 - A}, {y, 0, 1 - A}, {z, 0, 
            1 - A}], 0.01], {5, 2}]
        }}],
     {A, 0, .99}]
```

Rounding plus Padding prevents resizing of your output